# Dynamic site, using include to get content in specific div , how?

Tags: php, html, include

I want to use php to easily maintain my website, but I simply can't figure out the language - I've found some tuts online, and some other questions here, but none help me.

I've divided my site into some .php files, header/footer and such - And using 
 works fine..

Now I want the content  of my site, to update according to which menu I click on at my site.

http://dawtano.com/pp/

If I click on "about" I want the "Hello World" to open inside my content div, but I can't get the right php code to do it.

Comment: You still need to read tutorials. Read How URL is dispatched to controller and how controller is calling the view

Comment: @Shakti - @Matias isn't using MVC as far as I can see.

Comment: @adam: Still need to transfer control to proper files according to URL irrespective of he is using MVC or not

Comment: Yeah, but talking about dispatchers, controllers and views is way too over the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do this---

Note: This will only work if the CSS styling are on the current directory! ()

```
<div>
<?php
    $html_page = implode('', file('http://dawtano.com/pp/'));
    echo $html;
?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I got some help from a friend, and ended up with this code:
<?PHP 
if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = "main"; 
} else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

include($page.'.php');
?>

But I think I will try your code later on..

Comment: Welcome any time my friend, Matias!

Answer (score 0):

well currently your links are taking you to a separate page entirely. So why not just code it so that your include file is specific to the page. i.e, on about.php, use something like

```
include 'about_content.php
```

in your contetnt div.

If you're looking for your content to load dynamically into the content div you'll need to look into using ajax to fetch the content pages.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for some sort of Template Engine which allows you to create your pages out of variable parts. You could have a look at [TBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/), which is more or less what is suggested by the name. But there is a whole [lot more engines](http://www.google.de/search?q=php%20template%20engines) out there which could do the job.

If that's already too much over the top, maybe [Apache SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html) (Server Side Includes) are a try for you.

A little suggestion from my side, I am often using Apaches mod_rewrite in connection with a single controller.php file. Apaches mod_rewrite will then send all request to the controller.php which will fetch the appropriate page parts for the requested page using TBS and return the respective page. So you have the controll of the page in one location only.

To your original question **about.php** could look like:

```
<?php
  include('header.php');
?>

  // original page content as html for about.php
  // assuming header ends with the starting div <div> where you like the content to appear
  // and footer starts with the closing div </div>
  // if you need variable content here, simply use <?php echo $your_variable ?>

<?php
  include('footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One popular way to construct the site is to have a single php script which displays content based upon a $_GET variable like 'page' or 'content', and then make the link as:

```
'http://dawtano.com/pp/index.php?page=helloworldcontent'
```

Using this method, you would need to check if the variable ($_GET['page']) is set using isset(), and then make sure the string is safe... as anybody with a browser could just type in some mumbo-magic script and hijack your site:

```
'http://dawtano.com/pp/index.php?page=somecleaverlycraftedhax'
```

Once it exists and is safe, add the '.php' to the file name and include that file... if it exists! If it doesn't exist, then you will need some code to handle that, probably by displaying a 'File not Found' message, or redirecting home, or something.

I prefer not to do this because it is a pain to make safe, and I feel like it is pretty ugly. What I do instead is put all the header/footer/navbar/title bar scripts into seperate 'display' functions, and put them in another file.

Then include this file with the function definitions, and call all the 'display' functions to set up the page. So every php script in your site might look like:

```
<?php
  include 'html_display_functions.php';

  /* put lines here to parse $_GET and $_POST, session_start()/$_SESSION, etc... */

  print_html_pre_content();
  print '<p>Hello, world!</p>';
  print_html_post_content();
?>
```

Since every script will have this structure, you can just create a template file once. When you want to create a new page for your site, copy the template, rename the copy to the php filename you want, and add content between the two print functions.

You also keep the ability to modify the header/footer/navbar/title bar for the whole site in a central location, namely the included file with the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a switch statement:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Something like this:

```
<?php

include("header.php");
$page = $_GET['page'];

switch($page)
{
  case "about":
     include "about.php";
  break;

  case "faq":
     include "faq.php";
  break;

  case "help":
     include "help.php";
  break;

  default:
     include "home.php";
}

include("footer.php);

?>
```

Then just make all of your links look like this:
*http://www.example.com/index.php?page=home*

Just replace home with the correct page.